# AngularJS creating additional scopes on opening modal dialog multiple times

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angularjs-scope

I have a modal with angular-UI bootstrap. Because I've a dozen of different forms I want to show in the modal, I'm using a ng-include directive inside the modal. The src attribute is changing dynamically.

I saw the following behavior with batarang (even with a static src for ng-include):

Every time opening the modal, an additional scope is created! 
Because this modal will be opened and closed many times I will get dozens of new scopes and the application is getting very slow.

The **index.html**:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p><button class="btn" ng-click="showModal()">show Form</button></p>

  <div class="modal" modal="theModal" close="closeModal()">
    <div ng-include src="'form1.html'"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The **app.js** is quite primitiv:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showModal = function() { 
    $scope.theModal = true; 
  };

  $scope.closeModal =function(){
    $scope.theModal = false;
  };  
});
```

Comment: Here is the [plnkr run](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Mbo9OaKA8MFJptwmI3PN/) or [plnkr edit](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mbo9OaKA8MFJptwmI3PN)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in angular UI: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/232